# Showing fatal error call to undefined function _e() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, undefined-function

Please help me out

I have added a search box widget to my site http://www.immostwanted.com.
And when I am trying to search some item it is showing the error as
Fatal error: Call to undefined function e_() in /home/spencerj/public_html/immostwanted.com/wp-content/themes/proreview/search.php on line 13

Please help me out

Comment: can you post some codes from search.php?? we cannot help you with this  description...

Comment: I think the problem is here.this the 13nth line                   "<p class="post_meta"><?php e_("Posted by",'prt');?>: <?php the_author();?>   <?php e_("on",'prt');?> <?php the_time('F j, Y');?>   <?php e_("Under",'prt');?>: <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'category', '', ', ', '' ); ?></p>"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While in the title you say undefined function `_e`, the error message as printed says undefined function `e_`.

There is no function `e_`. The function should be `_e`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e